# SED : How to use variables

Tags: environment-variables, sed, bash-scripting

I'm making script for Post OS install which will be consisting of setting env for Apps and DB and also will include hardening. Doing this manually is not practical which takes hours when a Bash script can do in seconds.

Now for Hardening part I have to set Grub password.

using `sed` I use this command

```
sed -i '/timeout/ a password --md5 "$gpassword"' /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

also tried

```
sed -i '/timeout/ a password --md5 `grub_crypt' /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

But problem is this it just write

```
password --md5 "$gpassword"
```

in /boot/grub/grub.conf

Is there a way to overcome this and even a better way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are not expanded within `'...'`, you need to use double-quotes, like this:

```
sed -i "/timeout/ a password --md5 $gpassword" /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

Comment: Great it worked, so double quote was the problem

Comment: @OmiPenguin if this answered your question that perhaps you could upvote + accept it